# Modular web application using pure Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are trying to design a modular web application using spring. There are common core services(like database, logging , connect modules etc.) which can be used by other modules(can be different war files). I understand that OSGi is a good fit for this kind of use case, but i'd like to know if it can be done using pure spring. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just ordinary jars?

Comment: @chrylis Do you mean to say I need to add the core service jars as dependencies to my client modules?

Answer (score 0):

From a development point of view, you could take a look at the Onion architecture: https://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture

I guess you cannot use it to modularize your application into different war files but it can be quite useful if you for example want to keep your data access infrastructure completely separated from your business logic.

If you want to separate everything at runtime, another approach would be to use microservices but that does not imply a pure spring solution, however spring provides a good concept for microservices with the [spring-cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) project which integrates open source frameworks like eureka. (Originally developed by netflix.) If you can use spring-boot, the spring-cloud project is a really good starting point if you quickly want to get your microservices up and running. (Including service discovery and remote configuration management.)

Lastly, if everything you need is to separate development into several projects and your are already using maven for your dependency management, you could also separate your modules into single projects and handle them like any other dependency from 3rd parties. Depending on the size of your application, it might be worth to setup a Jenkins or any other build server and your own remote maven repository, so you do not need to build all dependencies locally on every dev-machine. We are using [Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi) for this task and are not having problems so far.

Comment: In my cases the projects are completely different, but they may use some common core services provided by the run time if they wish to. Basically i'll have multiple war files(not necessarily related in functionality) deployed in servlet container and I need to make some core services available as part of the container run time.  I'll have a look at the micro services to see if it fits my needs.